# Using one query to look up multiple tables with one input

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, sql

the query is at line 103 [This is the query I used (on Visual Studio Code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uRaP.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IFg5.png)I have a problem and I'll try to explain it. We have to create a functioning website for one of my classes, and one of the tasks is :
create an "input box" where the input can correspond to two different values (either "Kategorie" or "Description") and then once you click the search-button you have a table with all the information needed. 
I tried something like :
"SELECT ... FROM... WHERE kategorie=? OR description=? AND...
but it says that there is an syntax error...
Could anybody help me out?

Comment: Which part issues this error- Javascript, jQuery, or MySQL? Also, you need to share the **exact** error message, the code triggering that error, and your attempts to resolve this

Comment: This can have **many** reasons. How do you think we can help you if you don't show your code? Show your code.

Comment: update your question add  the  code you are using  and the exact error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have missed single quotes for kategorie and description values. Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE (kategorie='kat1' OR description='descr1') AND other='other value'
```